# Troubleshooting white screen when editing specific posts

Tags: admin, troubleshooting, fatal-error

I've run into a bit of a perplexing challenge. I'm working on a WordPress installation where certain posts, without a yet apparent rhyme or reason, throw a white screen when you attempt to edit them in the admin area. Its a large site with *lots* of plugins.

I've tried disabling all plugins to see if that made a difference. None.

I've been comparing the good posts to broken posts in the database, comparing wp_postmeta and wp_posts entries to see if I can spot any obvious difference. There are differences, but I don't see a consistent pattern and I'm not even sure that it would matter.

Any ideas on how you would troubleshoot this next?

Comment: If something is throwing fatal errors you should have the error messages in your server log.  Setting WP_Debug to true will also print the error msg to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up doing a repair database via phpMyAdmin and that solved the trouble.